# Introducing rate at which loops run in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, rate

I have function

```
x_i=(x_i-1)*normrnd(0,1);
y_i=(y_i-1)*normrnd(0,1);
```

I want to create a loop so that `x_i` is generated every, let's say, 1/10th of a second, for 10 seconds, so I can plot the `x` vs. `t` and `y` vs. `t` graphs. I am very new to MATLAB, so please help!
Thank you!

Comment: Why does it matter what time the sample was generated at? Just generate `(1/10)*10=1000` samples and plot them.

Comment: @Raab70, thank you that actually is true. But assuming that instead the functions are:
    x_i=(x_i-1)*normrnd(0,sigma);
    y_i=(y_i-1)*normrnd(0,sigma);
where sigma is a function of time, how would you do it? Thank you

Comment: `normrnd(0,1,1000,2)` will generate two columns of 1000 data points. I'm not sure what your scaling factor or `x_i-1` means though. Does this imply that you want each sample to be dependant on the previous sample, ie `x(i-1)`? This would be slightly different.

Comment: @Raab70, yes I believe so. Actually, I am having trouble simply generating 1000 samples and plot them (in response to your first comment, with sigma =1). Can you guide me quickly on how to do so?THank you

Comment: If you have `xy=normrnd(0,1,1000,2);` then you can plot them with `scatter(xy(:,1),xy(:,2))`